# How do you include a user's default image in a Drupal 7 view that lists people?

Tags: 7, views, media, users

I have a view in Drupal 7 that lists people (users). It shows the username and the standard user picture field. If a user has a set image, it comes through perfectly. However, for users that didn't set a profile image no image is shown, even though I have a default profile image set in the people settings for the site.

How do I get views to use the default profile picture for people that do not have a profile image set?

**Update**: I wasn't clear. I know how to use the default image in the no results behavior. The issue is that I can't get the default image to use the imagestyle I use for the other images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the path on the default image setting. Head over to your view and click on your image field. Look for "no results behavior". In the text area add

Verify that your view does not have hide if empty checked.

Save your view.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I know how to do that (and tried it). The problem is I can't get the image to pass through image cache to get the right size outputted.

Comment: How many of these are you doing? Would it make sense to cut the image yourself and link to it? Or are you using many instances in different sizes?

Comment: Yah, for this view just the one reduced size. I went ahead and cut the image myself.

Comment: In the future you can do a custom template for that field. Using PHP you can write a conditional that displays if the field is blank and call the image style  that you're using for resizing

Comment: @Justin: this is _NOT_ A SOLUTION! **You should mark [Marijke Luttekes's answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/33076/2368) as accepted**, because **her** answer REALLY solves the problem! Please look at my comment, I just tried it, and her solution worked perfectly. Thanks for changing the accepted answer to hers! :)

Comment: I wouldn't mind some extra rep points either :)

Comment: While this solution is correct,@Marijke Luttekes answer is better and will save you from having to add a fallback image on all of your views.

Answer (score 30):

I have just found the answer to this question via Drupal.org. You have to use a URI like this:

```
public://user_pictures/default.png
```

in your account settings.

Here, `public://` stands for your public files location (often `sites/default/files/`). What comes after that, is the location of your image within public files. If you do this, the default image is treated like normal user images.

Comment: +1, wow, you were absolutely right! On the `admin/config/people/accounts` site, I firstly set the default picture to `sites/default/files/user-pictures/person.png`; the result: no default images displayed in my view where I list users; after changing the path to `public://user-pictures/person.png`, the default picture appeared! I didn't think this is so simple. Thank you! :)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Adds the default user image with the correct image style without having to modify the view. Great answer.

Comment: really helpful and drupal way :)

Comment: The answer is correct, and I suggest to follow the relative bug report: https://drupal.org/node/1413824